# Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash, android-support-library

**Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState**

> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss
>   (FragmentManager.java:1842)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction
>   (FragmentManager.java:1860)
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal
>   (BackStackRecord.java:650)
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit
>   (BackStackRecord.java:609)
>   **> com.bharat.example.adapter.Articles_Adapter$MyViewHolder.onClick
>   (Articles_Adapter.java:147)**
>
> android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5201)
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:21163)
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:746)
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5443)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:728) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:618)

the crash occurred when at FragmentTransaction commit().

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = ((Content_Activity) main).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out, R.anim.right_in, R.anim.right_out);
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, "web");
                transaction.addToBackStack("home");
                transaction.commit();
```

using android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction

Answer (score 2):

Add this line. It is working fine to me.

```
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

Comment: This works because the common problem causing this error is that at some level you are mismanaging your fragments and FragmentManager is calling your fragment's `commit()` method after you have called `onSaveInstanceState(outState)`.  Ensuring your fragment's final state is not saved